# Does setprecision in c++ round? If so why am I seeing this?

Tags: c++, floating-point

The following snippet outputs 0.29847 when I would have expected 0.29848:

```
double f = 0.298475;
cout << setprecision(5) << f << endl;
```

For other examples, however, I observe rounding:

```
double f = 0.123459;
cout << setprecision(5) << f << endl;
```

outputs: 0.12346

and

```
double f = 0.123454;
cout << setprecision(5) << f << endl;
```

outputs: 0.12345

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The number `0.298475` isn't representable exactly in a `double` (since it's not a fraction whose denominator is a power of two, being 11939/40000), and the *actual* number that is stored is actually closer to 0.29847 than to 0.29848.

Comment: 0.298474999999999990318855225268634967505931854248046875, to be precise.

Comment: In other words, there are actually two rounding steps: one when the literal `0.298475` is converted to a `double`, and another when printing some number of digits to `cout`.

Comment: @dan04: That's a somewhat meaningless display; a 64-bit IEEE754 float only contains about 17 decimal digits worth of information...

Comment: @KerrekSB But as it's a rational number whose denominator divides a power of 10, it can be exactly represented as a decimal number. Doing that is often useful to clear up misunderstandings about rounding and display behaviour of floating point numbers.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Doing what can be useful? Note that we *started* with a finite decimal representation, so we have necessarily a rational number whose denominator divides a power of ten.

Comment: Showing the exact number the input gets converted to can be useful. If you give 17 significant digits, some people think you get 17 decimal digits, not 53 binary digits. So giving the precise value and saying that's `numerator / 2^exponent` may help bringing across the point. Sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see from the documentation setprecision() doesn't perform any rounding, but just sets the maximum number of digits displayed after the decimal point. Possible representations of double and float numbers may differ from the constant initializers you use.