# Why output of cout << setprecision(2) << 0.999 is 1 instead of 1.0?

Tags: c++, significant-digits

The significant digits is 2.

Why the output of

```
cout << setprecision(2) << 0.999 << endl;`
```

is `1` instead of `1.0`?

Comment: You mean `endl`. Right?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan yes, i mean endl

Comment: I hope answer below addresses your issue. Please accept his answer if it works to close it!

Comment: Isn't the real question here, why it is printing `1.0` instead of `0.9`?

Comment: Ah, my own question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922366/does-setprecision-in-c-round-if-so-why-am-i-seeing-this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default formatting does not print trailing zeros; you need to set the floating point formatting to `fixed`, see also [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed). So what you need is

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << 0.999 << endl;
```

Note also that setprecision refers to the decimal digits, so for 1.0 you would need `setprecision(1)`