# C++ setprecision only cuts off the digits.. it does not round

Tags: c++11

```
double d = 8.19999999999999999999;  
cout << d  << "\n";
cout << fixed << d  << "\n";
cout << setprecision(15) << d  << "\n";
cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << d  << "\n";
```

output

```
8.2
8.200000
8.199999999999999
8.199999999999999
```

Can I change that so it prints

```
 8.2
 8.200000
 8.200000000000000
 8.200000000000000
```

instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does setprecision in c++ round? If so why am I seeing this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922366/does-setprecision-in-c-round-if-so-why-am-i-seeing-this)