# How do I prevent decimals from rounding off when printed in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm doing my ICT homework and I ran into this problem: the decimals keep on getting rounded off when I print them. I've already included the `<iomanip>` header and used the `fixed` and `setprecision` manipulators, but it still keeps getting rounded off. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
     double num1 = 3.12345678
     
     cout << fixed << setprecision (4);

     cout << num1 << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, "3.1235" comes out instead of "3.1234," which is the expected output according to my teacher. How do I prevent the fourth decimal from rounding off?

Comment: That’s a question you’ll need to ask your teacher, since the answer your code is getting is the correct/expected one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does setprecision in c++ round? If so why am I seeing this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922366/does-setprecision-in-c-round-if-so-why-am-i-seeing-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69697709/941531) of @eerorika. You can use [std::fesetround()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) to set rounding strategy, as in code below. It outputs `3.1234` as you wished. Possible values for this function's argument are `FE_DOWNWARD`, `FE_TONEAREST`, `FE_TOWARDZERO`, `FE_UPWARD`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCsIwFET3@YqAm3ahoK0P2loQrNtCEQQ3EpNbCaQ3oUlEEL@9tqLS2c2ZGYYbM@WK4a3rJhK58gJoJrV1LbAmJ2PWMJRmjHgNeM8JkehowyQGIX0S2ktof1VA0Td0S6PZfBHFy9V6k35C60SS1GDBtdqjCA7F5ViedtX@XFRlOOpw7R3Nsu9APkD8XT82LXBppcYgDgc@nP1iQKFS8uq6Nw)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cfenv>

int main() {
    double num = 3.12345678;
    std::fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << num << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3.1234
```

Answer (score 2):

`3.1234` is not the expected output, `setprecision` will round to the specified precision.

One solution to get `3.1234` is to round to the desired number of decimal places yourself (`std::trunc` just rounds towards zero):

```
#include <cmath>
...
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);
std::cout << std::trunc(num1 * 10000) / 10000 << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent rounding i.e. you want to see more precision, you can use a higher value with `setprecision`.

If you want to round towards zero instead of rounding towards nearest, you can use the `FE_TOWARDZERO` rounding mode.

Comment: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9vqaqMeer)